# PHP Zend gData installation Checking Exception

Tags: php, gdata

I got this exception when i run the checking procedure for installation found there:

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/InstallationChecker.php

```
Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path which currently contains: .;C:\php\pear;C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\workspace\CPS\class\library\Gdata
```

I don't get it because this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\workspace\CPS\class\library\Gdata
```

Is the correct path to my gData library, and it's suppose to be standalone right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should had included the root folder so library directly and it's working fine